# How to remove default store view code from URL in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, default

I would like to remove the default store view code from the URL in Magento 2.1. How can I do this?

Comment: Please check my answer. And let me know if it's help

Answer (score -2):

You can add/remove store code from url same like magento 1. Follow below step:

1. Goto magento admin
2. Stores-> COnfigurations from Main menu
3. In the General section right side you can see Web Tab
4. In the Web tab there is field **Add Store Code to Urls** You can
   select suitable option for you from here. see below image.

[image]

Comment: The question is about ONLY the default store code, not ALL store codes. The setting pointed by your ads or removes store codes to url for ALL shop views.

Comment: for me it' work.